# How to create popup with YouTube video that not affect main page?

Tags: reactjs, youtube, youtube-api, video-streaming, popupwindow

I'm trying to have popup window with YouTube video that not affect the main page.

I can still interact with the main page, similar on [this](https://www.last.fm/search?q=muse][1]) web site when you click track you have small popup video on right bottom corner.

I have `App.js` with YouTube API

```
{     
  getYouTubeApi = (searchTerms1, searchTerms2) => {
    fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&q=${searchTerms1} ${searchTerms2}&type=video&key=YOUR_KEY`)
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>{
      this.setState({videoId: data.items[0].id.videoId})
    })
  .catch(error=>console.log(error))
  }

render(){
  return (<YouTube opts={opts} videoId={this.state.videoId} />)
  }
}
```

`getYouTubeApi` function I call on click on track that just bring to the top of my page where YouTube video loads.

[Here](https://musicboxflatironschool.herokuapp.com/) is my school project.

Comment: Have you tried on of these? https://react.rocks/tag/Popup

Answer (score 0):

Since this describes DOM behavior more than business logic, you could put in whatever you want in a specific component that behaves like a modal (whether by swapping out css classes or setting inline styles based on certain conditions).

To make this modal reusable, I'll suggest you make it a [higher order component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) to wrap around `<Youtube />` component or any other component you want to display with modals.

For example, you could have

```
const Modal = (ComponentToDisplayAsModal, props) => (
  <div class="modal">
   <ComponentToDisplayAsModal {...props} />
  </div>
)
```

You could then style the `modal` class to behave like a modal.

On the view you wish to show your modal, you could render

```
Modal(Youtube, props)
```